# How to configure trackpad gestures?

Tags: gnome, 22.04, touchpad, gestures

I upgraded to 22.04 and now there are weird trackpad gestures. I'm not talking about the awesome 1:1 new GNOME Gestures. I'm talking about these random weird ones where I accidentally pinch my fingers and it closes an application or maximizes it, or something that I don't expect.

How do I see what all these gestures are and possibly remove them?